# Supposedly easy visual puzzle - triangles and stars

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

My friend sent me a picture of this recently (unverified source) on social media. He says its from a practice job aptitude assessment. I think the pattern is very obvious.... but according to him the answer I gave him is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

> I'm pretty sure the answer is 2. Does anyone else agree?

Comment: At first glance this seems obviously correct, from both top-down and left-right perspective. Do you know what the intended answer was?

Comment: @jafe apparently the correct answer is apparently 1. I don't see any scenario where this would be the logical answer. Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe the idea is to challenge the guy telling you it is no.1

Comment: @PatrickSpalding I see one scenario - namely, when the puzzle author unintentionally mixed up the answers, so the picture intended to be No.1 ended up in the slot No.2, or (which is simpler) the solution list contains a typo.